# Python urllib encoding graphql POST data?

Tags: python, graphql, urllib

I am trying to make a POST request to a graphql server using `urllib`.  I can successfully accomplish this with `requests`, but I need to use `urllib` because reasons.

Here is a minimal example of the functional `requests` implementation ([link to graphql playground](https://swapi-graphql.netlify.app/?query=query%20MyQuery(%24pid%3A%20ID)%20%7B%0A%09person(id%3A%20%24pid)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D&operationName=MyQuery&variables=%7B%0A%20%20%22pid%22%3A%20%22cGVvcGxlOjE%3D%22%0A%7D)):

```
import requests
 
url = "https://swapi-graphql.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/index"
 
data = {
    "query": "query MyQuery($pid: ID) {\n\tperson(id: $pid) {\n    name\n  }\n}",
    "variables": {
        "pid": "cGVvcGxlOjE="
    },
    "operationName": "MyQuery"
}
 
response = requests.post(url=url, json=data)
print(response.content)
```

When I try to implement this with `urllib`, something about the encoding isn't working correctly, and I get a 400: Bad Request:

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

encoded_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode()
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=encoded_data, method="POST")
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    the_page = response.read()
print(the_page.decode("utf-8"))
```

If I delete the "variables" and "operationName" bits in my data dictionary, the request goes through, and I get the obvious complaint about the missing variable.... so, somehow, the problem is in my encoding of the `data` dictionary.

How can I properly encode graphql queries to use with `urllib`?